# How to prevent scaling of a web page

Tags: html, css

I am designing a web page that occupies only 80% of the horizontal space. On restoring the browser, the web page scales down automatically which makes it look very cluttered. I want that even on resizing the browser window, the web page does'nt get scaled but just gets scrollable. That is its size remains the same and it can be scrolled.

Comment: can you show the code/website/screenshot etc so we can see the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to define the site's initial scale and how zooming will be done. Add this tag to the `<head>` section:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">`

Answer (score 0):

If you want a fixed width you need to set a width if you didn't already.

```
body { width: 900px; }
```

could do it, unless there are more styles which override it.

Comment: hey, maybe you have'nt understood the question. i have huge stylesheets attached to the webpage for defining the width etc. but if a user scales his browser, the web page scales which i want to avoid. if u scale down your browser and open google or facebook, the web page does'nt scale down, but you have to scroll to view all the contents of google/facebook! thats what I am hoping to do.

Comment: @YashUpadhyay Do you mean using the browser-specific zoom functionality (Like Ctrl++ and Ctrl+- in Firefox) or simply resizing the window?

Comment: @YashUpadhyay And Google doesn't use a completetly fixed width either.

Comment: @YashUpadhyay This makes for a completely different question than what you posted originally. You should edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent the user from scaling the page by pressing `Ctrl +`, `Ctrl -` or `Ctrl Mousewheel`, maybe the following piece of code can work for you:

```js
document.body.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
    if (event.ctrlKey) { event.preventDefault() }
});
```

This will prevent the user from using the `Ctrl` key, so any functionality related to that would be lost.